# Intercepting link with intent-filter doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to intercept link so it will open my app, just like opening maps.google.com opens Maps app.

I have read other thread in SO about this but I don't know why I can't get this working.

I have this in my AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name="com.my_app.my_app.AppActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="flickr.com" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.flickr.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I tested with real device, using Dolphin browser. I entered www.flickr.com in address bar and it doesn't show any selection for selecting apps. I've tested dolphin to open maps.google.com and I can select whether to open with Maps app. So I think dolphin is not the problem.

I also have entered flickr from default browser. Didn't work either.

Is there something I missing here?

Comment: Did default browser call your app? I guess Dolphin handled the URL by its own engine… You can test by making another app and start an intent to flickr, if your app is shown up in a list then it's ok. I think you're doing right.

Comment: Default browser didn't call my app either. When I put maps.google.com in dolphin, I able to choose Maps app. So I think dolphin is not the problem why my app is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You can only intercept URLs when using an Intent to open the corresponding activity because the way it does it is by using the intent filters and intent resolution. When you type an address in the browser there is no intent, is just a method call. If dolphin shows you to open google maps, maybe it is something hardcoded into the Dolphin app, but it will not probably work with other urls or applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need add the android:path, android:pathPrefix or android:pathPattern attribute.

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="flickr.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.flickr.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
```